# Can ご無沙汰 be used in a sexual context?

Tags: usage, words, slang

I had asked my friend what uses of 「ご無沙汰」exist and the situations people use them in. Among others, she had remarked that it could mean something along the lines of "not having sexual intercourse for a long time". Is this really the case?

If so, who uses it and in what way? I have tried to find some source explaining this, but haven't as of yet.

Comment: Yes but I don't think that's feminine. And we use it in conversation too.

Comment: Interesting... Is it a case where using it in a conversation for its original meaning would elicit unintended giggles?

Comment: Haha.. No I think we usually know what is meant by the context. (We often say like 「"あっちの方は"ご無沙汰してる」or something when we mean "not having sexual blah blah...")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it can mean that implicitly. I feel like it would be something found in a "Women's Magazine" talking about sex life, so I feel it is somewhat feminine. Also, using polite speech in these ways is also feminine I think (or you might also find it on the cover of a pornography).

Comment: Would it be possible to give an example?

Comment: What kind of example? [Here](http://xbrand.yahoo.co.jp/category/lifestyle/4821/1.html) is an article from a Women's Magazine that uses the phrase.